# Error (-4, -4) for VideoView on Android

Tags: android, android-videoview

I get the following error :

```
02-10 13:19:21.607: E/MediaPlayer(12662): error (-4, -4)
02-10 13:19:21.622: I/MediaPlayer(12662): Info (1,26)
02-10 13:19:21.622: E/MediaPlayer(12662): Error (-4,-4)
02-10 13:19:21.622: D/VideoView(12662): Error: -4,-4
02-10 13:19:21.622: I/System.out(12662): onError-error play video
```

when I add a `VideoView` to a `RelativeLayout` and start it. After that I get the message from `onErrorListener`. Has anyone any idea what means this?

Comment: I don't think the problem is with the RelativeLayout and VideoView. The problem may be the video format/encoding.